# Get the super parent class method name hierarchy in the child class

Tags: java, string, inheritance, multiple-inheritance

I have the following program,

```
class A
{
    int i;
    B b_obj = new B();

    public void classAMethodStart()
    {
        system.out.println("class a method");
        b_obj.classBMethod();
    }
}

class B extends Class C
{
    public void classBMethod()
    {
        methodInClassC();
    }
}

class C
{
    public void methodInClassC()
    {
        //.. to do stuff
        //I want to get the ClassA method name here

         this.getClass().getName();
    }
}
```

when I try the following `this.getClass().getName()`, it gives output as

> java.lang.ClassB

The expected output I want to print is:

> classAMethodStart()

Comment: Can you include the call to `this.getClass().getName()` you added?

Comment: Class A is *not* a parent/super class of B or C. From class C's perspective, `classAMethodStart` is the caller method of the caller method, and there is no fully reliable way to get it. The best you can do is [`new Throwable().getStackTrace();`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Throwable.html#getStackTrace--).

Comment: This isn't `multiple-inheritance`. That involves extended two classes, which Java cannot do.

Answer (score 1):

## What `this.getClass().getName()` does

It gets the object being called on, and gets the name of its class, as your instance is an instance of B, it outputs `java.lang.ClassB`

## How to get the calling method details

You would need to get a stacktrace of the thread and walk back up it to get the calling method details:

```
class A {
  B b_obj = new B();

  public void classAMethodStart() {
    System.out.println("class a method");
    b_obj.classBMethod();
  }
}

class B extends C {
  public void classBMethod() {
    methodInClassC();
  }
}

class C {
  public void methodInClassC() {
    final StackTraceElement[] trace = Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace();
    System.out.println(trace[3].getMethodName());
  }
}

class Runner {
  public static void main(final String... args) {
    new A().classAMethodStart();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the `java.lang.StackTraceElement` to get the method name.

According to Java Docs:

> An element in a stack trace, as returned by Throwable.getStackTrace(). Each element represents a single stack frame. All stack frames except for the one at the top of the stack represent a method invocation. The frame at the top of the stack represents the execution point at which the stack trace was generated. Typically, this is the point at which the throwable corresponding to the stack trace was created.

A StackTraceElement has `getMethodName()`. Using this function, you have to trace back to the method you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

First of all here are the  few things I noticed from you code :
1. NOT UNDERSTANDABLE
2. NO INVOCATION(main method)
3. HAVE TO ASSUME THE CONTROL FLOW

basically your code is really bad at readability.

Now coming to the real issue :

**this.getClass().getName();** 

1.This refers to the implicit object passed to the method in other words the object on which the method was invoked.

2.getClass() as the method name suggest gives you the object of the type "Class" of class of object.

3.getName() gives you the name of the Class.

The java naming convention is so simple to understand here. That is if the method says getClass() the why are you expecting the method ??